# Efficient direct initialization of a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I have a struct, say

```
struct A {
  A(int n) : n(n) {}
  int n;
};
```

and I want to initialize a `std::vector` with some elements. I can do this by using an initialization list, or by emplacing the new elements:

```
// 1st version: 3 ctors, 3 copy ctors, 3 dtors                                           
std::vector<A> v1{1, 2, 3};

// 2nd version: 3 ctors                                                                  
std::vector<A> v2;
v2.reserve(3);
v2.emplace_back(4);
v2.emplace_back(5);
v2.emplace_back(6);
```

As the comments show, the first version calls 3 constructors, 3 copy constructors, and 3 destructors. The version with emplace only uses 3 constructors.

**Question**: Obviously the second version is better, but the first version is more succinct. Can I have the best of both worlds? Can I do a direct initialization without the extra cost?

(Here's a [longer version](http://hastebin.com/idagalivaf.cpp) of the `A` struct that shows what's happening.)

Comment: Your version with `emplace_back`-s has no extra cost in terms of calling methods of `A`. Since you want to have vector of size = 3 at the end, it is absolutely necessary to call 3 constructors. `emplace_back` perfectly forward your arguments into constructors of elements.

Comment: (I deleted a comment I made a moment ago - I was wrong. I had forgotten about the role of the initializer_list on this.)

Comment: @stgatilov Yes, the version with `emplace_back` is efficient. I want to have initializer lists with the same efficiency. Is it possible? Why does it need 3 copy constructors and 3 destructors? Theoretically it shouldn't...

Comment: @stgatilov: I've edited the question part, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @vukung: In the case of the brace-intialization, the compiler creates 3 temporary `A` objects to populate the `std::initializer_list` that it passes to the `std::vector` constructor, then those values are copied into the `A` objects that are allocated within the `std::vector`, and then finally the temporaries are destructed after the `std::vector` constructor exits.

Comment: @vukung, to clarify. You want the efficiency of `emplace_back`, but without having to type out `emplace_back` three times? Which would be annoying if you had much more than three to type. Also, direct initialization allows the `vector` to know the size in advance and allocate accordingly

Comment: `std::array` works well here. Directly constructed in place. Possibly perfect for your application, unless you need to change the size of the container after it's constructed?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Actually I don't have an application, this is sort of a theoretical question. It seems strange to me that the standard does not require this optimization on initialization lists. But yes, `std::array` could be a solution.

Comment: @vukung, I never really look at the implementation of init lists before, but now I've looked into them in more detail I am not entirely impressed with them. Their `begin` method returns a `const` pointer, meaning that they can't be moved from. I had assumed that init lists were designed to be moved from! There are many things I would change about them actually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `A` is convertible from `int`, you can use the range constructor of `vector`:

```
auto inits = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<A> v1{std::begin(inits), std::end(inits)};
```

Or in a single declaration-statement (assuming you can rely on RVO):

```
auto v1 = [inits={1, 2, 3}] { return std::vector<A>{std::begin(inits), std::end(inits)}; }();
```

Comment: Nice! So if I use a range constructor, there is no copying involved. Strange that it's not the default behavior for the direct initialization...

Comment: @vukung it's because vector only has an `initializer_list` constructor for its element type, and `initializer_list`s are only really efficient for literal types. A converting `initializer_list<U>` constructor would only be useful for types `T` convertible from `U`, so I guess they didn't bother.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @ecatmur's answer, I've developed a piece of code that allows a very general solution for any type of vector and for any constructor calls. The constructor parameters for each element of the vector are stored in a `tuple` (of `&` or `&&` as appropriate) which are then perfect-forwarded when the element is built. Each element is constructed only once, essentially equivalent to `emplace_back`. This forwarding would even allow a vector of move-only types to be built such as `unique_ptr<?>`.

(*Update*, due to RVO it should simply construct them in place. Unfortunately, however, the element type does require at least a copy-constructor or move-constructor to be visible, even if they are actually skipped by the optimizer. This means you can build a vector of `unique_ptr`, but not of `mutex`.)

```
auto v2 = make_vector_efficiently<A>(
         pack_for_later(1)        // 1-arg constructor of A
        ,pack_for_later(2,"two")  // 2-arg constructor of A
        ,pack_for_later(3)        // 1-arg constructor of A
        );
```

The above code will create a `vector<A>` with three elements. In my example, `A` has two constructors, one which takes `int,string` as parameters.

`pack_for_later` builds a `tuple` that stores its parameters as `&`/`&&` references. That is then converted into on object (of type `UniquePointerThatConverts`, that has the desired conversion operator, in this case `operator A()`.

Within `make_vector_efficiently`, an initializer list of these converter objects is built and then `vector` is constructed with the `begin()` and 
`end()` of the initializer_list. You might expect that these iterators would be required to have type `T*` in order to construct a `vector<T>`, but it is sufficient that the type the iterator points to can *convert* to `T`.

The constructor then uses placement `new` to (copy-)construct from the converted object. But, thanks for RVO, the copy won't happen and the converter will be effectively doing the equivalent of `emplace_back` for us.

Anyway, any feedback appreciated. Finally, it's trivial to extend this to other containers besides `vector`.

---

[Full code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d72aec69eb97d78) Should work on any C++11 compiler.

---

Some more detailed notes, and copies of the important functions:

`pack_for_later` simply builds a `std::tuple`. The standard `make_tuple` isn't good enough as it ignores references. Each element of the tuple built by `pack_for_later` is a reference (`&` or `&&` as appropriate, depending on whether the original parameter was an lvalue or rvalue)

```
template<typename ...T> 
std:: tuple<T&&...> pack_for_later(T&&... args) { 
        // this function is really just a more
        // 'honest' make_tuple - i.e. without any decay
    return std:: tuple<T&&...> (std::forward<T>(args)...);
}
```

Next, `make_vector_efficiently` is the function that brings is all together. It's first parameter is the 'Target' type, the type of the elements in the vector we wish to create. The collection of `tuples` is converted into our special converter type `UniquePointerThatConverts<Target>` and the vector is constructed as discussed above.

```
template<typename Target, typename ...PackOfTuples>
auto make_vector_efficiently(PackOfTuples&&... args)
    -> std::vector<Target>
{
    auto inits = { UniquePointerThatConverts<Target>(std::forward<PackOfTuples>(args))...};
    return std::vector<Target> {std::begin(inits), std::end(inits)};
}
```

Because `A` can have multiple constructors, and we want to be able to use any and all of them, `pack_for_later` can return many different types (don't forget about lvalues and rvalues too). But we need a single type to build the init list from. Therefore, we define a suitable interface:

```
template<typename Target>
struct ConvInterface {
    virtual Target convert_to_target_type() const = 0;
    virtual ~ConvInterface() {}
};
```

Each tuple is therefore converted to an object that implements this interface by `make_Conv_from_tuple`. It actually returns a `unique_ptr` to such an object which is then stored in a `UniquePointerThatConverts` that has the actual conversion operator. It is this type that is stored in the init list which is used to initialize the vector.

```
template<typename Target>
struct UniquePointerThatConverts {
    std:: unique_ptr<ConvInterface<Target>> p; // A pointer to an object
               // that implements the desired interface, i.e.
               // something that can convert to the desired
               // type (Target).

    template<typename Tuple>
    UniquePointerThatConverts(Tuple&& p_)
    : p ( make_Conv_from_tuple<Target>(std:: move(p_)) )
    {
        //cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    operator Target () const {
        return p->convert_to_target_type();
    }
};
```

And, of course, the actual conversion operator which constructs from the pack.

```
template<typename Target, typename ...T>
struct Conv : public ConvInterface<Target> {
    std::tuple<T...> the_pack_of_constructor_args;
    Conv(std::tuple<T...> &&t) : the_pack_of_constructor_args(std:: move(t)) {}

    Target convert_to_target_type () const override {
        using idx = typename make_my_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)> :: type;
        return foo(idx{});
    }
    template<size_t ...i>
    Target foo(my_index_sequence<i...>) const {
        // This next line is the main line, constructs
        // something of the Target type (see the return
        // type here) by expanding the tuple.
        return {
                std:: forward
                    < typename std:: tuple_element < i , std::tuple<T...> > :: type >
                    (std:: get<i>(the_pack_of_constructor_args))
            ...
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Great work! I still have to wade through the details, but looks like a general solution.

Comment: I made a little tweak to the code on Coliru, and updated the link here. A specialization for `my_index_sequence<0>` was missing, and this is needed to call default constructors (i.e. in order that `pack_for_later()` works). Also, I've discovered that this won't work for `vector<mutex>` because RVO doesn't allow you to skip the need for a copy-constructor or move-constructor to be present (even though they'll never be called under RVO).

Comment: Nice! I'm a bit baffled by how `map` has `emplace(piecewise_construct, [tuples])` but `vector` et al do not. Perhaps - and especially if this is easily generalised as you said - you could submit a library proposal? It seems like the kind of thing that should just exist out-of-the-box - and indeed, _does_ elsewhere. I also wonder whether C++17's guaranteed copy elision could help you out with the requirement for visible copy/move ops? Lastly, is it me, or does your example create a vector with 3 elements, not the claimed 4? :S